# Java Thymeleaf how to replace file

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm writing application to encryption and decryption files. I'm struggling with uploading and saving file. I'm correctly sending file from my html input to Controller, inside controller bytes are encrypted but how after that save that file in same path?
It should looks like: user choosing file to encrypt, clicking "Encryption" button and then choosen file is replaces by new (encrypted) one.

I've tried to use .transferTo from MultipartFile interface but it doesn't work.

Have anyone some hint how to solv that problem?

Here is my html:

```
<form th:action="@{/crypto/encryption}" th:object="${file}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label class="file">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" aria-label="File browser example" style="position: relative; margin-top: 300px; right: 400px;">
        <span class="file-custom"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="encryption"></label>
    <input type="submit" id="encryption" name="encryption" class="parallelogram" value="Encryption" style="background-color: blue;">
    <label for="decryption"></label>
    <input type="submit" id="decryption" name="decryption" class="parallelogram" value="Decryption" style="background-color: blue;">
</form>
```

and my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/crypto")
@Controller
public class EncryptionController {

    @Autowired
    private EncryptionService encryptionService;


    @PostMapping("/encryption")
    public encryptFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptionService.encryption(bytes);

        File f = convert(multipartFile);
        multipartFile.transferTo(f);
    }
}
```

I'll be really appreciate for any help.

## Edit

Problem solved. I've used FileOutputStream.

```
@Service
public class FileService {


public void saveFile(byte[] fileBytes, File f) throws IOException {
    String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(fileBytes);
    fos.close();
}

public File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
    convFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
    fos.write(file.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    return convFile;
}
```

}

Comment: Don't hesistate to post your answer it might help others :)